# Relationship between spin and wave-function (in geometric algebra)

Tags: wavefunction, quantum-spin, spinors, clifford-algebra

I am interested in determining which 'feature' of the wave-function are responsible for fixing the spin of the matter is relates to; or more precisely, an "algorithm" or "procedure" to output the spin, given the wave-function.

According to David Hestenes the relativistic wave-function, in the language of geometric algebra, is

$$
\psi = \sqrt{\rho} e^{ib/2}R
$$

where $R$ is a rotor.

Does this object carry enough information to fix a spin value, say of 1/2? How does one determine the spin this wave-function allows?

Does one need more than just the definition of the wave-function; is the Dirac equation also required?

Is there a relationship between spinor and spin-value of 1/2? How do I get the value of $s$ (the spin) from this formulation of $\psi$?

Comment: Which reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/pdf/SpacetimePhysics.pdf equation 29, page 6

Comment: @Qmechanic I guess in a sense, I am asking which elements of $\psi$ turns when we refer to the spin; it is the rotor, the pseudo-scalar I? Do any elements of the wave-function transforms as it spins? And can we relate that to 720 degrees to make a full rotation? For instance, I was imagining that the rotor R, or the pseudo-scalar $e^{ib}$ have to do a 2 full turn to return to the original position. Can this be shown? If not the rotor or the pseudo-scalar, what in $\psi$ needs to do two full turn to return to the original position? Or maybe I am thinking about this wrong?

Comment: *How does one determine the spin this wave-function allows?* Same way as usual? Apply a rotor $R_\theta$ and see what $R_{2\pi}$ if it returns, e.g., $-\psi$.

Comment: @KyleKanos So I am looking for $R_{2\pi} \psi \tilde{R_{2\pi}}=-\psi$ for spin 1/2? In 1+1 space-time this is explicitly as follows: $e^{e_0e_1 \theta /2} \sqrt{\rho} e^{e_0e_1 B}  e^{-e_0e_1\theta/2}$

This gives 
$$e^{e_0e_1 \theta /2} \sqrt{\rho} e^{e_0e_1 B}  e^{-e_0e_1\theta/2}\\
 =\sqrt{\rho} e^{e_0e_1 \theta /2+e_0e_1 B -e_0e_1\theta/2}  \\
=\sqrt{\rho} e^{e_0e_1 B }\\
=\psi 
$$

So everything is spin 1?

Comment: @KyleKanos Or do I need to only apply it one-side as follows $R_{2\pi} \psi$?

Comment: Rotor on one side. For the spin-half, $\psi'=R_\theta\psi=\mathrm{e}^{\hat{B}\theta/2}\psi\to\left(\cos\pi-\hat{B}\sin\pi\right)\psi=-\psi$ for the constant bivector $\hat{B}$.